# SVNSYNC: mirror server different dimension with master after failed transaction

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svnadmin

I have one master server and one mirror server (each [VisualSVNServer](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/)) synchronized by SVNSYNC.

After a failed synchronization my svn mirror server is growing up of 50MB (compared to the master).

Master svn server is 45 MB with 401 file, mirror now is 100 MB with 18.000 file.

After investigation, I found all the file in the dirs:

1. F:\Repositories\MyRepo\db\transactions  (master is empty dir)
2. F:\Repositories\MyRepo\db\txn-protorevs (master is empty dir)

I have tried to clean with [svnadmin rmtxns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.rmtxns.html):

```
svnadmin rmtxns F:\Repositories\MyRepo
```

but nothing changes.

How can i clean this wasted space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify txn name for `svnadmin rmtxns` command to work:

```
$ svnadmin rmxtxns --help
rmtxns: usage: svnadmin rmtxns REPOS_PATH TXN_NAME...

Delete the named transaction(s).

Valid options:
   -q [--quiet]             : no progress (only errors to stderr)
```

You may use `svnadmin lstxns` command to get list of repository transactions.